# Hero Widget does not work in case of a custom page route

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I have created a custom Page Route to act as a bottom dialog inspired by the IOS action sheet popup, I have the Page route working perfectly, now what i want is a hero Transition between the my first route and the next Popup route.

I have created a dartPad demonstartion showing the problem => https://dartpad.dev/e79bd9adf6845857e0829ec6fe5a4a55

Let me know if there is anything else that you need from my end.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations 
Use `PopupRoutes` is not support right now

Heroes fly from one `PageRoute` to another. Dialogs (displayed with showDialog(), for example), use `PopupRoutes`, which are not `PageRoutes`. At least for now, you can’t animate a hero to a Dialog. For further developments (and a possible workaround), watch this issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10667.